# Problem format hdfs during installing hadoop

Tags: bash, hadoop, ubuntu-18.04, java-home

I get this error below when I try to format my HDFS by runing this command:`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs namenode -format`  in my Ubuntu 18.4 machine:

```
/home/mohamedamine/Downloads/hadoopWork/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 304: /home/mohamedamine/Downloads/hadoopWork/jdk1.8.0_101/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I'm using [this](https://www.guru99.com/how-to-install-hadoop.html) documentation to install hadoop.

I googled for the same problem and I find all answers talking about checking the java path.
I check all java path and I'm sure that all correct.
Below my ./bashrc content

```
#Set HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/mohamedamine/Downloads/hadoopWork/hadoop

#Set JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=/home/mohamedamine/Downloads/hadoopWork/jdk1.8.0_101

# Add bin/ directory of Hadoop to PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

Below also my java path in the `hadoop-env.sh`

```
# The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME=/home/mohamedamine/Downloads/hadoopWork/jdk1.8.0_101
```

I try also this path

```
# The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME=/home/mohamedamine/Downloads/hadoopWork/jdk1.8.0_101/jre
```

But always the same error.
I'm using hadoop 2.7.3 version.

If you could show me how to resolve this error it would be greatly appreciated.Thanks a lot

Comment: The tutorial you linked seems to have used the `jdk1.8.0_05` version on their system. I don't believe you did something wrong, but I do believe that since Hadoop is heavily dependent on the java version it is used upon. Did you try to install the `jdk1.8.0_05` version to repeat each step? Just to make sure I guess.

Comment: No I don't try the jdk1.8.0_05 version but I will test it now

Comment: What does `which java` shows you?

Comment: It shows nothing

Comment: Try to standalone install java on your system and set _that_ installed version as the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable path.

Comment: @Coursal really thanks it's work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a problem include in the version of jdk I don't know maybe oracle delete some file from new version.
So it's work when I switch from jdk 1.8.0_101 to jdk 1.8.0_05.
Below the link of old versions of jdk from oracle archive:
[Java archive](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html#license-lightbox)

Comment: Version doesn't matter. I think the issue is that you really shouldn't install the JDK to your downloads folder